# Подключение Firebase

Tags: android, android-sdk

пытаюсь подключить Firebase. Выбивает ошибку ***Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0.***  **Удаляю** `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'`, **добавляю** `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'` и  `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'`. Синхронизирую, вроде все ок. Нажимаю еще раз ***"Add the Realtime Database to your app"***  и мне опять пишет, что хочет добавить в код `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'.`В чем проблема ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы подключить Firebase необходимо:

В `build.gradle` на уровне проекта добавить:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

В `build.gradle` на уровне приложения добавить:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Актуальные версии на данный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Советую пока не использовать 16.0.5

---

[Источник](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0)

Comment: а строку[ implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5' ] не нужно добавлять ?

Comment: @Влад Надо, только не 16.0.5, а 16.0.4. Обновил ответ.

Comment: сделал как написали, нажимаю "Add the Realtime DataBase to your app", добавляется 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0' , но стоит галочка возле 2 пункта и пишется "Dependencies set up correctly". Но пишется ошибка "Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0".  Это критично ?

Comment: @Влад https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmidHtiFfA8

Comment: Но там второй пункт не отмечается как выполненный.  Должно же быть написано "Dependencies set up correctly". Или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: @Влад  Дополнительно добавь `jcenter()` в `build.gradle` на уровне проекта. Обновил ответ.

Comment: а о он там и был добавлен